# Creating a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What is a comprehensive source on learning how to create a ruby gem?

Is their a paid solution e.g., book?

I'm not finding much on the internet and on here except for basic tutorials which don't cut it.

Comment: For anybody else arriving here via Google: https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md is the answer.

Comment: https://shivab.com/blog/ruby/2019/08/30/convert-your-ruby-script-to-a-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 4):

The definitive guide is the RubyGem’s own [Make Your Own Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) (plus the [other guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/)) along with the [Gem Specification reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/).

The Bundler’s [`bundle gem` command](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/bundle_gem.html) is also useful for creating a good skeleton project.

Comment: Thank you, I read it over. I did come across this, but it seemed very brief.

Comment: @Brian - Why does it have to be long? There is not enough to say about the subject to be able to write a book about it. Have you tried to follow those guides? Or did you just dismiss them because they're short?

Comment: Hi Mischa, yes I did dismiss, but I am starting to read over the RubyGems docs. I understand what you're saying. I was just looking for a good test driven (rspec / cucumber) gem example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all yourself, or you can let another gem do the work:

[Step by step outline](http://www.slideshare.net/hagenburger/create-yourowngemwithgithubjewelerrubygems) to creating and publish a gem using the [Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) Gem.  More detailed instructions [here](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/craft-the-perfect-gem-with-jeweler/).